# Is there any source or database from which we can find out the total number of military aircraft sold globally every year?

Tags: military, aircraft-identification

There are a few online databases that sheds light on the number of commercial jets that countries, airlines purchases every year.

Is there any database that provides similar figures for military aircraft sold annually around the world every year ? In case exact figures are not available, approximates will do.

Comment: A lot of governments make spending data public, SR-71 style stuff aside you can likely find the data if you are willing to go through enough reports...

Comment: @Dave     Does such a database exist for the US military?

Comment: I doubt an exact number is available since that would pose a national security risk. It would have to be approximations extrapolated from annual defense budgets.

Comment: @CarloFelicione Ok ! Approximates will do

Comment: As a "database", probably not. Buried deep within appropriations and/or budget bills of various countries, you'll probably be able to come up with reasonably close numbers. My guess is you'll need plenty of caffeine to keep yourself awake reading deep enough to find it all.